# How to apply Bootstrap CSS into a Ractive.js template like Handlebars does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, handlebars.js, ractivejs

I'm thinking in replace Handlebars.js with Ractive.js.
The change seems smooth but this is my first problem and can be a newbie question.

I have a Ractive.js template which contains a table. The table in the template has several Bootstrap classes

```
class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"
```

When I use this template with Handlebars.js the Bootstrap styles in the table are shown ok, as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/HeLaw/).

But when I use the same template with Ractive.js the styles are not shown, as you can see in  this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/HcZ8H/).

I tried adding the classes manually:

```
$("#table").addClass("table")
$("#table").addClass("table-striped table-bordered")
$("#table").addClass("table-condensed table-hover")
```

Without success. I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: a bit unrelated, but there are some handy shortcuts here: http://dagnelies.github.io/ractive-bootstrap/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need `<tbody>` for bootstrap tables to work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcZ8H/2/)

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you.

Comment: I used to write thead and tbody all the time, but today I didn't. It's a little strange that the styles work in Handlebars.js without tbody.

Comment: I am not really familiar with handlebars.js or reactive.js tbh. But if you look at the output html from handlebars.js example in jsfiddle under F12 tools, you will see <tbody> there.

Comment: Interesting! It turns out it's not something that Handlebars is doing, but something the browser is doing - when you do `element.innerHTML = '<table><tr>...'`, the browser inserts the missing `<tbody>` for you. Ractive builds the DOM up programmatically, so the browser doesn't interfere, and as a consequence the Bootstrap CSS selectors don't work. Arguably, that should be considered a bug in Ractive - I'll raise an issue.

Answer (score 3):

With Ractive 0.4.0, you can create a component to encapsulate a bootstrap table:

```
<script id="bootstrap-table" type="x-template">
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" >
        <tbody>
            {{>content}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Then use it in place of `<table>`:

```
<script id="templateOne" type="x-template">
    <bootstrap-table>
        <tr> 
            <th>
                Column one
                ...
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PCcqJ/2/

Comment: That's cool. When will be Ractive 0.4.0 ready for production?

Comment: Announcement should be any time now on @RactiveJS

Comment: fyi - Ractive 4.0 is out